# IoTA full node setup done but all transactions pending

Tags: iri-node, iota-network, node

I have followed http://iota.partners/ to setup a full node on my AWS. I am pretty sure that my security policy has opened the port for IoTA.

The neighbor status:[image]

and then when my program status check
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what could be wrong. You might want to delete the complete database and redownload it by following the Step6 of that guide. Before doing so, my advice is to locate your mainnetdb folder and delete all its contents. Assuming you have it at /opt/iri/mainnetdb you should do.

```
cd /opt/iri/mainnetdb
rm -rf *
```

Once the mainnetdb folder is empty and while you are still on it

```
cd /tmp/ 
wget -P /tmp/ http://db.iota.partners/IOTA.partners-mainnetdb.tar.gz
tar xfvz /tmp/IOTA.partners-mainnetdb.tar.gz -C /opt/iri/mainnetdb
```

Once the database files finish copying, edit your iri config file and add the line:

```
DB_RESCAN = true
```

To the bottom. Then just restart your Full Node, make sure you have some active neighbors and see if it gets going.

**Important:** once you start your IRI and it get synced be sure to remove the line added (DB_RESCAN = true) from your config file. Otherwise you will rescan the complete database on every restart which will take a long time.

If you are having problems, you might wanna try [this guide](https://forum.helloiota.com/2424/Setting-up-a-VPS-IOTA-Full-Node-from-scratch). It might no be as complete as the one you used but you will get a Full Node running by following the steps!